# Selecting a good test solution for Cyclic Voltammetry

Tags: cyclic-voltammetry

So I have a textbook headed my way for this but need to get a head start.

I have a 3-electrode voltammetry setup but I want to test it for some standard values (for educational purposes) before I start working on my actual project. For now, I'd like to use the equipment I have to run Cyclic Voltammetry tests at a basic, neutral, and acidic pH to verify that it's reading correctly and that I know how to read it.

Problem is, I've been out of Chem for a while. So asking about choosing test chemicals is sort of a multi-pronged question.

- Given some chemical, say Potassium Ferrocyanide in a water and KCl solution, how do I calculate the pH? I've seen the equations concerning hydron concentrations, but I'm not too sure how to calculate hydron concentrations (had a little difficulty finding info).
- Will performing this calculation tell me anything about the reversibility of the redox reaction, or is that something that it typically found empirically?
- Is there anything else I need to be aware of in doing this calculation?

Sorry for the spread question, but I'm just getting started with all of this.

Oh, as a note, I have Pt and AgCl for my electrodes (AgCl wire and I should be getting an AgCl electrode soon).

Thanks!